# outputting a for loop result to a file from Jenkins using a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

I'm trying to generate directory listing with full path using below one-liner from the command line.

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /ad "D:\myWork\organization"') do @echo D:\myWork\organization\%i
```

It works fine by listing the sub folders under it like;

```
folder_1
folder_2
folder_3
.....
.....
```

but if I do the same from Jenkins's windows execute batch command option, I'm facing below error message.

```
do @echo D:\myWork\organization\%i > output.txt was unexpected at this time.
```

Command used from Jenkins.

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /ad "D:\myWork\organization"') do @echo D:\myWork\organization\%%i > output.txt
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In batch files, double the `%`-signs: `for %%i in (...) do (...)`...

Comment: @aschipfl : Thanks much, that helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins writes this command line into a temporary created batch file and executes this batch file with `cmd.exe /C`.

Open a command prompt window and run `for /?`. The fourth paragraph in help output starts with:

> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable.

So you have to write in Jenkins:

```
@for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /ad "D:\myWork\organization" 2^>nul') do @echo D:\myWork\organization\%%i
```

In other words you have to use `%%i` instead of `%i` as this command line is executed by Jenkins by writing this line (and others) into a batch file and execute it with Windows command interpreter.

By the way: You could also use this command line:

```
@for /D %%I in ("D:\myWork\organization\*") do @echo %%I
```

That would be a bit faster, but ignores hidden subdirectories in `D:\myWork\organization`.

Comment: that was a great explanation +1.